# Trying to make a "locate me" button on React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I'm trying to make a simple "locate me" button on a React Leaflet map that I created.
This is the library I am using: https://github.com/thijssmudde/react-leaflet-locate-control.
Everything works without a hiccup before I use this library to create the "locate me" button. Then I follow the instructions in the aforementioned page and everything crashes.

Here's what I added in my code.
`import LocateControl from 'react-leaflet-locate-control';`

First red flag is here. When I hover over `react-leaflet-locate-control` in VSCode, I have a message indicating (loosely translated as my VSCode is in French) that the declaration module file of that name is not found. Odd... I did do a yarn add and it does appear in my package.json.

In my functional component, I added this:

`const locateOptions = { position: 'topright', strings: { title: 'Show me where I am, yo!' }, onActivate: () => {} // callback before engine starts retrieving locations <-- **not sure what do add here!!** }`

Later I return a `<MapContainer>`, and inside is a `<LayersControl>` for my tiles and GeoJSON data.. After that, I added:
`<LocateControl options={locateOptions} startDirectly/>`

I get this error: *Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Locate is not a constructor*

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I tried using `leaflet-locatecontrol` but that was worse as it's not made for React.
I tried asking ChatGPT, but that was like turning in circles!